# Passing an enum to a web service from php

Tags: php, web-services, enums

I'm trying to consume a web service where one of the methods takes an enum as an input.

SendSms(SoapUser user, string originator, string smsData, string
recipientPhone, MessageType messageType, string defDate, boolean blink,
      boolean flash, boolean private)

Here's my code :

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://link-to-wsdl');

$smsresult = $client->SendSms((array("user" => array("CustomerID" => 1, "Name" =>"test","Language"=>"en","Password"=>"secret"))),"originator","smsData",
"recipientPhone","Latin",NULL,false,false,false);

var_dump($smsresult);
```

When I run the above code i get the following error :

> FATAL ERROR Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR:
>   Encoding: object has no 'messageType' property in
>   /home/phptest/public_html/code.php53(5) : eval()'d code:12
>
> Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/phptest/public_html/code.php53(5) : eval()'d
>   code(12): SoapClient->__call('SendSms', Array)
>   #1 /home/phptest/public_html/code.php53(5) : eval()'d code(12): SoapClient->SendSms(Array, 'originator', 'smsData', 'recipientPhone',
>   'Latin', NULL, false, false, false)
>   #2 /home/phptest/public_html/code.php53(5): eval()
>   #3 {main} thrown on line number 12

I'm unable to figure out how to pass the messageType parameter(which is a string)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to post questions about an error you must clearly indicate code on the offending line number.

Comment: As a guess, would "messagetype" parameter expect a Mime type?